# Region of Interest Uniqueness and Identity

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently working a computer vision application with OpenCV. The application involves target identification and characteristic determination. Generally, I'm going to have a target cross into the visible region and slowly move through it in a couple of seconds. This should give me upwards of 50-60 frames from the camera in which I'll be able to find the target.

We have successfully implemented the detection algorithms using SWT and OCR (the targets all have alphanumeric identifiers, which makes them relatively easy to pick out). What I want to do is use as much of the data as possible from all 50-60 shots of each target. To do this, I need some way to identify that a particular ROI of image 2 contains the same target as another ROI from image 1.

What I'm asking for a little advice from anyone who may have come across this before. How can I easily/quickly identify, within a reasonable error margin, that ROI #2 has the same target as ROI#1? My first instinct is something like this:

1. Detect targets in frame 1.
2. Calculate certain unique features of each of the targets in frame 1. Save.
3. Get frame 2.
4. Immediately look for ROIs which have the same features as those calc'd in step 2. Grab these and send them down the line for further processing, skipping step 5.
5. Detect new targets in frame 2.
6. Pass targets to a thread to calculate shape, color, GPS coordinates, etc.
7. Lather, rinse, repeat.

I'm thinking that SURF or SIFT features might be a way to accomplish this, but I'm concerned that they might have trouble identifying targets as the same from frame to frame due to distortion or color fade. I don't know how to set a threshold on SIFT/SURF features.

Thank you in advance for any light you can shed on this matter.

Comment: Thanks for the style edit Matthieu :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is locally equalize brightness and possibly saturation levels. If you aren't using an advanced space such as YCrCb or HSV, I suggest you try them.

Can you assume that the object is not moving too fast? If you feed the previous position in the detection routine, you can decrease the size of the window you are looking at. Same thing goes with the speed, and direction of movement.

I've successfully used histogram composition and shape descriptors of a region in order to reliably detect it, you can use that or add it to a SURF/SIFT classifier.

Comment: The idea to equalize brightness sounds like a promising one, I'll look into it. 

We can assume the object is not moving very quickly, and that in fact is one of the underlying assumptions in our calcs for GPS coordinates. I'm going to implement some sort of discrete filter (probably a Kalman) for the 'random variable' of GPS lat/lon, using as many frames as possible for the measurements. Trouble is, I need at least two positions to find the initial velocity. 

Can you elaborate on histogram composition and shape descriptors?

Comment: Sure. These two are statistics on the image. A histogram of a hue channel for example should be similar to the object in the database's histogram. The positions of the peaks, their heights and relative heights, along other factors should be close.

Comment: As for shape descriptors, you can use Hu moments. There's a good wiki article on them. The CvBlob library implements some of the moments. These two methods are fairly easy to implement, the key is to binarize the image in a consistent way. For many applications a basic threshold or adaptive threshold are not good enough.

Comment: Okay, I've dealt with Hu moments before and that's a decent place to start. They're very lightweight and quick to calculate, and we could compare them with reasonable margins to the DB'd target very simply. 

I really like the idea of comparing histograms, but I'm not sure how to do that programatically. Do you know of any good tutorials on that?